# Android Support Repository Manager

Tags: android-studio-3.3

I need to solve this problem.

[image: Hi, I need to solve this problem.]

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue. what exactly are you trying to do ? When did you get this error ?

Comment: when i try to build my first program i get this error

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says, ***Install Android Support Repository.***

In your Android Studio, just open, Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager

Here you can find it, Extras -> Android Support Repository